# Why is it necessary to have a two sides identity for the existence of inverse elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that it is a must from the definition, but I don't get it intuitively.

Why does a set with one side identity and one side inverse elements has no meaning in the math world?

For example, (N, -) including 0. zero is the one side identity, and every n element has the inverse element n. So 1-1=0, 2-2=0 and so on.

Comment: What is the meaning of the inverse of an element?

Comment: If the identity is not included in the group, then the group is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe did you mean to say if the identity is not included *and inverses are*, then closure fails? Sort of true, but you are presuming that the the set and operation are embedded into some ambient group, which doesn't have to be the case in general.

Comment: If  $a$ and $ a^{-1}$ are elements of the group, then whatever $a\cdot a^{-1}$ equals must be in the group. And, by definition, $a\cdot a^{-1}=e$ the identity.

Comment: I can understand why the identity must apply on one side but not both left and right. For example if we have the natural numbers including 0 and the binary operation minus, 0 is the identity from the right but we can't say that 7 is the inverse number for itself (for example) because 7-7=0.

Comment: Intuitively, does it make sense for an inverse to exist if you have no identity? Imagine taking 5 steps forwards and then taking 5 steps backwards and not ending up where you started? (Assuming each step is of uniform distance etc. etc.)

Comment: What don't you get? An inverse is defined via an identity element. Without identity there is no such thing as an inverse.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Lets take for example the binary operation "minus" on the natural numbers set(including 0). Why 0 cannot be considered enough to have inverse numbers? for example, 7 is the inverse number for itself because 7-7=0.

Comment: The identity (*with no other qualifications*) of a binary operation $\star$ is an element $e$ such that for any other element from the set $a$ one has $e\star a = a\star e = a$.  The binary operation $-$ on the integers does not have an identity.  Although $a-0=a$ it is not true that $0-a=a$ as well (*except in $\{e\}$ and in $\Bbb Z_2$*).  You could talk about "right identities" or "left identities", but these are fundamentally different than actual identities.

Comment: +1 because I think a good answer for intuition will actually take some work.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509772/why-is-it-necessary-to-have-an-identity-for-the-existence-of-inverse-elements#comment5183344_2509772), it seems that you may have meant to ask "Why isn't it sufficient to...?" instead of "Why is it necessary to...?"

Answer (score 1):

As ÍgjøgnumMeg pointed out, the OP mentions group theory in his tags and this is probably the main source of confusion. Let us come back on OP's example, namely $(\mathbb{N}, -)$. Not only it is not a group, but the operation is only partially defined. Even if you consider $(\mathbb{Z}, -)$, where the minus operation is fully defined, it is still not associative. However, $0$ is indeed a right identity since $x - 0 = x$ for all $x$. Technically speaking, the algebraic structure $(\mathbb{Z}, -, 0)$ is a [*pointed idempotent quasigroup*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) or *pique*.
In this setting, each element $x$ has a unique *left inverse*, namely $x$ (since $x - x = 0$) and $-x$ is its unique *right inverse* (since $x - (-x) = 0$). Observe that this left inverse and this right inverse only coincide when $x = 0$.

**Technical note**. In a quasigroup, an element $a$ has a left-inverse $a^L$ (respectively a right-inverse $a^R$) if the condition $a^L(ab) = b$ (resp. $(ba)a^R = b$) holds for all $b$. This notion **does not** require the existence of a left (resp. right) identity.

Comment: So in (N, -), n can be considered the inverse of n because n-0=n and n-n=0(0is the right identity)?why did you write that it is not fully defined?

Comment: This is not fully defined because, for instance, $1 - 2$ is not a natural number. Thus it is preferable to work in $(\mathbb{Z}, -)$. In this case, $0$ is the right identity (but it is not an identity) and $n$ is the left inverse of $n$ (but it is not a right inverse, and therefore, not an inverse).

Comment: By not fully defined you mean not a closed set. So n is an inverse but only a left inverse, but why did the book writer decide to mention that it has no meaning?

Comment: Sorry, which book and which book writer?

Comment: Not an english book. And I quote: "When the set has no identity from both sides, there is no need to discuss about inversion."

Comment: OK. Thus the book writer is not interested in left or right inverses, but only in inverses. And his definition (which is the most accepted one) requires the existence of a two-sided identity, say $1$ in multiplicative notation. Now an inverse for $x$ is an element $y$ such that $xy = 1 = yx$. In this setting, having a two-sided identity is part of the prerequities and hence inversion does not make sense if you don't have a two-sided identity.

Answer (score 0):

We could say that we can have two (or three or four, or $\cdots$) but it would still mean that there is just one.

Say we have $e, e'$ as identity elements. Then we have $e=ee'=e'$.

But I believe that your confusion arises from explicitly including the identity element on the definition of a group. We don't have to, we can define a group with an equivalent definition but from that we will again derive the existence of an identity element which as depicted above-will be unique.

Comment: My confusion arises because we can take the minus operation on the natural numbers(including 0), and 7-7=0, but 7 is not considered to be the inverse number for itself.

Comment: No, but $-7\in \mathbb{Z}$ is. And who talked about the natural numbers forming such a  group as you imply? A group consists of a set and a relationship we define on that set. ${\mathbb{N},+}$ is *not* a group.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Note that OP never used the word "group". :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks for this. It tells a lot that I made that implication myself. You have me wondering now if my answer is salvageable!

Comment: You are clearly not the only one who's locked in tunnel vision here.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m talking about sets. I don’t care about -7, I apply the binary operation “-“ on natural numbers. So 7-7=0.  7 is not considered the inverse of 7, why is that?

Comment: @MorHaham In light of Dustan's remark I will have to ask you-In the beginning of your question you say " it is a must from the definition". ***Which definition do you have in mind?***

Comment: OP mentions group theory in the tags used.

Comment: On a chapter for sets in a book that I read(not english): “There is no meaning for inverse numbers property without an identity”. The definitions are the familiar ones. Just wanted to understand why the example that I mentioned above doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @MorHaham Well, this simplifies things somewhat. How would you go about defining an inverse element if there was no identity? In layman's terms-identity serves two purposes:when multiplied by an element it gives the same element. In $\mathbb{N}$ for example it does just that and nothing more. But it can also give meaning to the inverse of an element ***in respect to a certain relation***. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ that relation is $+$ and the identity element is $0$ since $a+0=0+a=a$ and $a+(-a)=0$.

Comment: Why one side identity is not enough? 0 is a one side identity in (N, -).

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=(G,*)$ be a group. Remember that an inverse for the element $x \in G$ is an element $y \in G$ such that $x*y=e=y*x$, where $e \in G$ is the identity (i.e. $g*e=e*g=g$ for all $g \in G$) and  we write $y=x^{-1}$.

Think of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. What is the inverse, $a$, of $-2$. What is $-2+a$? And $a+(-2)$?